# Objective C / Xcode

Tags: objective-c

What would be example code for objective c to give a button the function of disappearing??

Comment: You should get a book about Objective-C and start learning from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an outlet to your `UIImageView` called **myImageView** and an action for your `UIButton` called **myButtonHit**.

```
-(IBAction)myButtonHit:(id)sender {
    self.myImageView.hidden = !self.myImageView.hidden;
}
```